# Ho to increase Java heap space for jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

While running my test after some time i got below error like "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
Could some one please help me how to increase java heap space for jmeter.

2018-08-16 18:57:07,765 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2018-08-16 18:57:14,745 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-6
2018-08-16 18:57:14,745 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 7):

For JMeter 4.0 default settings are:

```
-Xms1g -Xmx1g -X:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

For Windows you can amend them in 2x times:

```
set HEAP="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -X:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m" && jmeter.bat
```

For Linux/Unix/Macosx:

```
export HEAP="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -X:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m" && ./jmeter.sh
```

Also make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: Where can i change this settings in jmeter

Comment: For windows open jmeter.bat file and edit above configuration